# Solr "error adding field" error for a date column

Tags: solr

While indexing my database data to solr,it`s throwing error like

"HTTP Status 400 - ERROR: [doc=12903] Error adding field 'CAD1'='2012-05-02T08:03:00'".

I have caught this error in fiddler.
In solr schema xml, I have this code for date columns or data

```
"<field name="CAD1" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

"

And i`m using solr version 3.5.
Plz ask me if i`m missing something here.plz suggest me a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding 'CAD1'='2012-05-02T08:03:00Z'.

Comment: :Thanks for the answer...this didn`t work for me,I`m using Oracle 10G and it`s failing to fetch data.Plz suggest me anyother way.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to restart SOLR after making updates to your `schema.xml` file.